# Github how to merge branch to main?

Tags: git

I have `main` and branch `myStudy`.

And I want to merge myStudy to main.
But I keep facing this issue message.

```
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive (untracked content)
```

In order to reflect these 4 commits, I tried to do below:

(1) checkout myStudy
(2) git add .
(3) git commit -m "~"
(4) git push origin main

But when i do (3) commit, it throws same error.

```
On branch myStudy
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact your *local* branch main is *ahead* of 'origin/main' by 4 commits means you don't have anything to do to "reflect those 4 commits": they are already there:

```bash
git switch main
git merge myStudy
git push
```

Regarding

```
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive (untracked content)
```

That means you have untracked content in a subfolder Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive declared a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**:

```
cd Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive
git status # check if you are on a branch
git branch -avv
git switch main # if you were not on a branch but there is an origin/main
git add .
git commit -m "Add new content to Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive"
              (replace it with a more meaningful comment)
git push
cd ..
git add . # to record the new submodule tree/SHA1
git commit -m "Update Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive submodule"
git push
```

Comment: ok thanks, but when I want to reflect change to main, keep facing this issue: 
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   Modern-JavaScript-Deep-Dive (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: @hyejung OK, I have edited the answer to include the  submodule part.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch
git checkout main 
git pull 
git merge <your_branch_name>
git push
```

fetch branch (if doesn't exists in your local),then switch to the merging branch

Comment: Yes, but that does not address the "`commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules`" part. See my answer.